# How to test if a river affect another?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statsmodels, chemometrics

I have two rivers, two monitoring stations placed in each river, and two datasets. One river is a tributary of the other.
The datasets are complete, pH, metals, field parameters (flow, temperature, conductivity, turbidity).
How I would approach a problem like this? I need to know if the tributary river could affect the other. The tributary river is like 1/5 flow of the other but is more acid (ph < 5), and we need to know whether that acidity is strong enough to make more acid the bigger river (ph ~ 7) or not.
We have one sensor in the tributary river, and two sensor in the bigger one (see image below)

[image]

Comment: Let’s consider the Snake River as a tributary of the Columbia River. Do you have the sensor on the Columbia upstream or downstream of where the Snake meets it?

Comment: Yes, we have. I added an image.

Comment: How do you expect to measure the change in pH in the Columbia River if you don’t know the pH before the tributary? Perhaps you have some domain knowledge about what the pH of a river should be. How’s you get that ~7 pH number?

Comment: In fact, those number were taken from samples of both rivers.  I have more than 10 years monthly data of those parameters. I want to demostrate statistically that the one upstream does not affect the downstream one.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. You’re dumping Snake River acid into neutral Columbia River water. You’re going to wind up with somewhat acidic water in the Columbia River by $c_1v_1=c_2v_2$.

Comment: This seems like perhaps an aqueous chemistry question at first order, rather than a statistical question? For a purely physical mixture model (i.e. no extra chemistry; as in [this example](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/32092)?), [H+] scales exponentially with pH, so 2 orders of magnitude difference for 5 vs. 7 would overpower < 1 order of magnitude difference in discharge I would think (as suggested by @Dave). So this would imply some extra chemistry is needed to buffer the acidic inflow, no?

Comment: pH sensors are rather cheap. I don't understand why you didn't install a third sensor upstream. Do you know the buffer capacities? You should consult with a chemist. You first need to create a chemistry model before this can turn into a statistics problem.

Comment: we have a third sensor, sorry I didn't mention it.

Comment: Does monthly really mean that there is only one measurement per month? Observation frequency is much lower than the flow of the river?

Comment: Yes, one measurement per month, for more than 10 years.

Comment: With higher frequency data I would us a granger causality test. But with low frequency data I would just run a linear regression of 1 against 2 and 3, or of the difference between 1 and 3 against 2, and then check how large and significant the effect of 2 is.